# Translating MySQL trigger to SQLite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I wonder if anyone can help me translate a pre-update trigger from MySQL to SQLite. Here's the MySQL trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name 
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `table_name` 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.fk IS NOT NULL AND NEW.status < 50) 
  THEN
    BEGIN
      DECLARE obj_count INT(11); 
      SELECT COUNT(*) 
      INTO obj_count
      FROM (SELECT id FROM table_name
                            WHERE `status` < 50 AND fk = NEW.fk
                            LIMIT 1) AS objs;
      IF (obj_count > 0) 
      THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '23000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = "Error.";
      END IF;
    END;
  END IF;
END
```

My undesrstanding is that the SIGNAL statement needs to be rewritten like this: `SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'Error.')`

But there are other syntax errors that I am having a hard time understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLite triggers](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) have neither IF nor DECLARE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE UPDATE ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.fk IS NOT NULL
 AND NEW.status < 50
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, "Error.")
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id
                  FROM table_name
                  WHERE status < 50
                    AND fk = NEW.fk);
END;
```

(`BEFORE UPDATE OF fk, status ON table_name` might be more efficient.)